# How to validate a Geometric point using a Java Regular Expression?

Tags: java, regex

I tried like this - To validate a point like x,y

"[0-9]{1,},[0-9]{1,}"

Its not working.

UPDATE:

I must be doing something wrong. This is a simple Console input through Scanner(System.in) - using Scanner#nextLine which returns a String.

```
private static String REGEX_PATTERN = "[0-9]{1,}[,][0-9]{1,}";
private static Pattern regExPattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_PATTERN);
private static Matcher regExMatcher;

regExMatcher = regExPattern.matcher(getStringValue());
isValid = regExMatcher.matches();
```

I tried svrist's solution too. It didn't help.

Comment: When asking for help with regular expressions, it would be useful to give some samples of input that should match, and maybe some that shouldn't. And in general, don't just say "It's not working", explain *how* it is not working and what you *expected* to happen.

Comment: did you really try `x,y`? your regex matches `number,number` strings.

Comment: "its not working" does not sound like a valid error message

Comment: I tried with 4,5 - Its not working means - the regex doesn't match my input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working:

```
public class Test {

    private static String REGEX_PATTERN = "[0-9]{1,}[,][0-9]{1,}";
    private static Pattern regExPattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_PATTERN);
    private static Matcher regExMatcher;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test("1,3");  // true
        test("123");  // false
        test("1-3");  // false
        test("123,456");  // true
        test("123, 56");  // false
        test(" 23,456");  // false
        test("123,456\n");  // false
    }

    private static void test(String string) {
        regExMatcher = regExPattern.matcher(string);
        boolean isValid = regExMatcher.matches();
        System.out.printf("\"%s\" - %s%n", string, isValid);
    }
}
```

maybe `getStringValue()` is returning some extra character like white-spaces or line-feeds.
To ignore the spaces try with

```
REGEX_PATTERN = "\\s*\\d+\\s*,\\s*\\d+\\s*";
```

Comment: Yeah. Try either the debugger or    `System.out.println("|"+getStringValue())+"|")` and give us some test-data that "doesnt work"

Comment: My mistake. The variable was overwritten before the correct output is shown. Thanks folks.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found what you are looking for:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/132735-coordinates-regex/

Answer (score 1):

If you tried "4,5" and it doesn't work, then something else is wrong.

```
tjwebb@latitude:~$ rhino
Rhino 1.7 release 2 2010 09 15
js> /[0-9]{1,},[0-9]{1,}/.test("4,5");
true
```

For me, "4,5" does match, so you must not be *using* that regular expression correctly. It looks correct to me. What language are you using?

-tjw